# How to properly use class from one file in another file?

Tags: php, class, include

I have one file DHMOFramework/lib/Core/Core.php with this code:

```
<?php

namespace DHMOFramework\lib\Core\Core;

/**
 * Main DHMOFramework class
 */

$registeredCommands = [];

class Core
{

  function registerCommand($command) {
    global $registeredCommands;
    $registeredCommands[$command] = [];
  }

  function registerSubCommand($commandname, $subcommand, $args, $helpmsg) {
    global $registeredCommands;
    $structure = array('command' => $commandname, 'subcommand' => $subcommand, 'args' => $args, "helpmsg" => $helpmsg);
    array_push($registeredCommands[$commandname], $structure);
    echo $registeredCommands;
  }

}
```

And I have another file test.php with this code:

```
<?php

require_once "DHMOFramework/lib/Core/Core.php";

$dhmo = new Core();

$dhmo->registerCommand("command");
$dhmo->registerSubCommand("command", "subcommand", ["arg1" => [true, string], "arg2" => [true, boolean]], "Usage: /command subcommand <arg1> <arg2>");
```

And I keep getting this error when I run the test.php file:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Core' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.php on line 5

Call Stack:
    0.0001     232464   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.php:0
```

How ca I fix this?

Comment: please include the absolute path to both files. ie: /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.php

but where is DHMOFramework/lib/Core/Core.php relative to your workspace? (better if you just have the whole thing like maybe it's located at /home/ubuntu/workspace/DHMOFramework/lib/Core/Core.php ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full class name:

```
$dhmo = new DHMOFramework\lib\Core\Core\Core();
```

Or use a `use` statement before using the class:

```
use DHMOFramework\lib\Core\Core\Core;
$dhmo = new Core();
```

Check out Namespaces in [Official PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: I just tried the use statement and the full class name. Neither work and I get the same error.

Comment: I missed one Core in the fully qualified class name. Edited the answer.